# Problems creating a Delete Trigger to prevent some rows to be deleted

Tags: mysql, triggers, phpmyadmin

im trying to make my first delete trigger but im having a lot of errors. My goal is to create a trigger that prevents some rows to be deleted from a table, where the "created_id" equals 0.
I'm creating it on PHPMyAdmin. First i wasn't able to even create the trigger because i got a lot of errors. I was finally able to create this trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER `prevenirBorrado` 
BEFORE DELETE ON `entidades_tipos` 
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN 
    IF entidades_tipos.created_by = 0 THEN 
       SIGNAL SQLSTATE 'U0042' 
       SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'STRSQL No puedes borrar este registro!' ; 
    END IF ; 
END
```

But now it won't let me delete any record from my table, getting this error:
SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1109 Unknown table 'entidades_tipos' in where clause

I was thinking about making AFTER DELETE and use 'ROLLBACK' but im not able to create the trigger without errors.

Thanks.

Comment: Try: [db-fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/mrpSnj5D).

Answer (score 0):

The SQLSTATE will raise an error. You could try adding an empty CONTINUE HANDLER immediately after the BEGIN statement.

Something like:

```
BEGIN

DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR SQLSTATE 'U0042' BEGIN END;
```

Also you need a semicolon at the end of your trigger declaration.

Comment: buddemat. Why did you 'edit' this answer? You did not change anything.